# Hiding and show info jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

am trying to hide Message and show alert message after 5 seconds
but not working.

i want after clicking submit then after 5 seconds i hide Message and show alertMessage

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Submit").click(function(event) {
       Execute();
        setTimeout(function(){
        \$("#alertMessage").show();
        \$("#Message").hide();
        }, 500);
    });

    function Execute(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: {},
         success: function(res) {},
        error: function() {
          alert("failed");
        }
      });
    };

  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <style>
    .hideMessage{display:none;}
   </style>
   
   
    <div id="alertMessage" class="hideMessage"> This is alert message. </div> 
    <div id="Message"> default text. </div>
```

Comment: What's the HTML for your `#submit`?  Is it a `<button type='submit'` (or `<button>` without submit?)  Along with removing the hideMessage class, it looks like your page is refreshing (check the browser network tab) so it *looks like* it's not doing anything as the page is reloading before the timeout.  Add `return false` to the end of your submit click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `alertMessage` has a class (`hideMessage`) which keeps it hidden when calling `.show()` - specifically `.show()` only changes the `style` of the element(s), it doesn't know about your custom class.

Change `class="hideMessage"` to `style='display:none'` to have it show with .show()

```
<div id="alertMessage" style="display:none;"> This is alert message. </div>
```

*or* change your "show" line to

```
$("#alertMessage").removeClass("hideMessage")
```

Here are two snippets that demonstrate it working.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  $("#alertMessage").removeClass("hideMessage");
  $("#Message").hide();
}, 1500);
```

```css
.hideMessage { display: none; }
#alertMessage { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="alertMessage" class="hideMessage"> This is alert message. </div>
<div id="Message"> default text. </div>
```

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  $("#alertMessage").show();
  $("#Message").hide();
}, 1500);
```

```css
.hideMessage { display: none; }
#alertMessage { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="alertMessage" style='display:none;'> This is alert message. </div>
<div id="Message"> default text. </div>
```

Comment: its not working, it only hides the Message but not showing alertMessage

Comment: I've added two snippets with the different solutions.  If these don't help, please update your question to include what you've tried (from the above) that's not working - you can remove the ajax code as that doesn't appear to be relevant.

Comment: But it *does* hide the #Message?  Not a problem with reloading the page then (see my comment against the question)